# Use cases for protected subnets

Tags: amazon-web-services, subnet, amazon-vpc

I'm reading through some blog posts and articles on aws vpc design to see if there are perhaps improvements to be made to a setup currently on aws when I came across an article making mention of "protected subnets" [here](https://blog.rackspace.com/network-segregation-aws-2).

> Protected – internal subnets that have only private IP addresses associated to the resources and are not accessible from the internet. They are NOT able to access the Internet.

We currently make use of public/private subnets in all AZs to ensure segregation of access and resources. However I'm failing to see a use case for the above type of subnet (perhaps it's just not applicable to our situation?) since any resources within the subnet cannot access nor be accessed from outside the vpc.

Are there any common scenarios where a protected subnet would come in useful?

Answer (score 2):

There are many reasons. Here are a few, but there are many more cases.

**SECURITY:**

By launching instances in private subnets, they cannot be accessed from the public Internet. These instances can be accessed by other means such as thru load balancers.

**STABILITY:**

You may want locked down instances that do not change, meaning no patches, no software updates, etc. I use this case all the time. When we want to update an instance, we actually deploy new AMIs and do not update the instances. We test the new AMIs with all new patches before deployment.

**HYBRID ENVIRONMENTS:**

In this case, the private subnets only have a VGW (Virtual Private Gateway) which allows access from the private data center to access the instances in the private subnet. Active Directory instances would be an example of this.

Note: Just because an instance is located in a private subnet, this does not mean that at certain desired points of time the instances cannot access the Internet. By adding a NAT Gateway, NAT Instance, etc for a period of time will allow Internet access (from the instance to the Internet).

Comment: Thanks for the response, however I think you misinterpreted the question. We currently do make use of private subnets and NAT gateways since our web servers need to interact with external services, my inquiry is about the protected subnet which is defined as a subnet that lacks both a way to be reached from outside the vpc (like a private subnet) but also lacks any connectivity to the internet.

Comment: I did not misunderstand your question. My item "Stability" covers one reason for no public access. Note: You can still access an instance in a private subnet via private IP addresses. Rackspace's use of the word "protected" is not an AWS term but would fall under #2 in the following list. In AWS there are three types of subnets. 1) A subnet with an IGW. 2) A subnet with only private IP addresses and an optional NAT Gateway / Instance 3) A subnet with only a VGW.

Comment: I see, greatly appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

I do use private subnets for RDS databases and for EC2 instances that are behind loadbalancers. They are not to be accessed directly by the public, but they can be accessed internally by other resources in the VPC and can communicate with the exterior through NAT gateways.